# Text inside anchor tag not showing up

Tags: html, css, text, anchor

The text that I have between my anchor tag is not showing up and I do not have any idea why. Can anyone help me out?

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
<a class="links" href="#footer">Yolo</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.links{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:30px;
border-bottom:2px solid orange;

padding:10px 0px;

color:red;

}


#left{


background-color:#320E7F;
position:relative;
right:85%;
top:120px;
height:1900px;
width:100%;
z-index:0;

}
```

Comment: its showing up in the fiddle I tried it on ..  I think the problem is somewhere else !

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/2cQx3/

Comment: hmmmm....maybe the problem is with the div its in....

Comment: yeah please post all relevant code here..

Comment: Why don't you show us the div as well?

Comment: #left{
 
 
 background-color:#320E7F;
 position:relative;
 right:85%;
 top:120px;
 height:1900px;
 width:100%;
 z-index:0;
 
}

Comment: You are missing closing double quote to id attribute of your div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have an unclosed attribute here: `<div id="left>`

Second, your rule `right: 85%;` pushes the div to the left, where your link is, so it's rendered out of the screen.

See it fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/2cQx3/2/

Comment: Yes, technically it's visible, but outside of the viewable area.

Comment: No problem! You can easily debug errors like these using browser's Dev Tools, just so you know.

Comment: I haven't used that yet, but I will know look this up

Comment: You definitely should, either by pressing F12, or by right-clicking an item and selecting Inspect Element (in most browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:relative` for `div`. You will be wanting this..

**CSS**

```
.links{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:30px;
border-bottom:2px solid orange;

padding:10px 0px;

color:red;

}
#left{ background-color:#320E7F;  right:85%; top:120px; height:1900px; width:100%; z-index:0; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
<a class="links" href="#footer">Yolo</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2cQx3/1/